# Update a component with onChange. React-Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a dropdown with suggestions that fetch data from an API. The input from the search bar is being stored using setState and it is updated when i change the value in the text input.

The thing is that I'm not managing to update the users lists from the dropdown each time I enter a new character in the text input. Can I somehow force the component to be rendered every time the props change? Or is there a better approach?

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import Dropdown from '../Dropdown/Dropdown';
import './SearchBar.css';


// Component created with arrow function making use of hooks
const SearchBar = (props) => {

    const [input, setInput] = useState('');
    const [dropdownComponent, updateDropdown] = useState(<Dropdown input={input}/>)

    useEffect(() => {updateDropdown(<Dropdown input={input}/>)}, [input])

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setInput(e.currentTarget.value)
        updateDropdown(<Dropdown input={input}/>)
        console.log("=(")
    }



    return(
        <div className="search-bar">
            <input type="text" placeholder={props.placeholder} onChange={onChange}/>
            {dropdownComponent}
        </div>

    )
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: It would help us help you if you included a **runnable** [mcve] using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including hooks and JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Comment: \* including hooks -- you have to update the version of React, the dropdown list in the UI hasn't been updated in a while. Just pick the latest and then change 16.6.3 to 16.10.2 in the two script tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't make the problem happen using your code in a simple test, but your `onChange` does have a problem: It's using `input` to update the dropdown, but it's not using `useCallback` to ensure that `input` isn't stale when it does. Either:

1. Don't update the dropdown in your `onChange`, allowing your `useEffect` callback to do it; or
2. Use `e.target.value` instead of `input` and get rid of the `useEffect` updating the dropdown; or
3. Don't memoize the dropdown (e.g., don't put it in state) since you want to update it when the input changes anyway, just render it directly in the JSX

Of those, with what you've shown, #3 is probably the simplest:

```
const SearchBar = (props) => {

    const [input, setInput] = useState('');

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setInput(e.currentTarget.value);
    };

    return(
        <div className="search-bar">
            <input type="text" placeholder={props.placeholder} onChange={onChange}/>
            <Dropdown input={input}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

function Dropdown({input}) {
    return <div>Dropdown for "{input}"</div>;
}

const SearchBar = (props) => {

    const [input, setInput] = useState('');

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setInput(e.currentTarget.value);
    };

    return(
        <div className="search-bar">
            <input type="text" placeholder={props.placeholder} onChange={onChange}/>
            <Dropdown input={input}/>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<SearchBar />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.10.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.10.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I had implemented the option 3 before. For some reason it doesn't update, maybe because of how the child component are build. I will try to post a runnable example.

Comment: @FelipeSouza - Give me a shout if you need any help with doing that. You can get most things from cdnjs.com. You usually need the "UMD" version of things.

Comment: in the end I found the issue. The component responsible for fetching the data was calling the API only on componentDidMount and not on componentDidUpdate. I changed it and the problem was solved. After that I converted the code to use hooks like the others. 

Thank you so much for the help. Also, I didn't know about the Live Example. I'm going to use that in the future for sure.